# Laravel7 : Validate uploaded files

Tags: laravel, file, validation, laravel-7

I have a form to get the file from the user and I validate the file format with the following rule:

```php
$valid = validator($request->only(['files'],[
    'files' => ['nullable', 'array'],
    'files.*' => ['mimes:zip,rar,jpeg,jpg,png,txt,doc,docx,pdf','max:25600']
]);
```

As you can see, I said accept text files as well. But I want to accept only `text/plain` files.
But for example, it also accepts Python files because they are `text/x-python`.
I even added the `mimes.php` file to the `config` folder and put the following code in it. But it still accepts Python files.

```php
// config/mimes.php

<?php

return [
    'txt' => ['text/plain']
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mimetypes` rule rather than `mimes`. That way you can specify rules as:

```php
$validated = request()->validate([
  'files.*' => ['mimetypes:text/plain, ... '],
]);
```

Reference: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-mimetypes)